# Modify spark dataframe structure using pyspark and converting to list of dictionaries produces null datetime values

Tags: list, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, timestamp

I have a spark dataframe called df structured as follows:

| ID | values | datetime | ID2 | Port | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | [01/01/23, 02/01/23, 03/01/23, 04/01/23, 05/01/23,] | ab1 | 7 | 16 |
| id2 | [3, 6, 9] | [01/01/23, 02/01/23, 03/01/23 | ab2 | 64 | 27 |

I want to convert the dataframe into a list of dictionaries called all_parts.  The dictionary will basically have the ID, then I would like a second part called 'form' that contains both the values and datetimes as sub values, i.e. part['form']['values] and part['form']['datetime].  So I have the following structure ultimately:

```
part['ID'] = df['ID]
part['form']['values'] = df['values']
part['form']['datetime'] = df['datetime']
part['ID2'] = df['ID2']
part['port'] = df['Port']
part['TotalTime'] = df['TotalTime']
```

I've managed to solve this issue by doing the following code:

```
all_parts = []
for row in df.collect():
    part = {}
    part['ID'] = row['ID']
    part['form'] = {}
    part['form']['values'] = row['values']
    part['form']['datetime'] = row['datetime']
    part['ID2'] = row['ID2']
    part['port'] = row['Port']
    part['TotalTime'] = row['TotalTime']
    all_parts.append(part)
```

However, when I check the data, everything works, however, the datetime values are returned in the list as null values.  The datetime field is a timestamp datatype with each value increasing by 20 milliseconds.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue using your sample dataframe. can you share more details on your problem - e.g. code you ran, what is the output for `df.show(2, False)`, what's the output for `df.limit(2).collect()` -- *side note, your approach can be streamlined to unlock full pyspark capability*

Comment: The only difference with my sample code is that the datetime field is actually a spark timestamp data type in the following format: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS+0000.  The code I ran is exactly the same as in the example.